# Django query not working in script but works in shell

Tags: django, shell, django-models

Whenever I run my script, my queries for one model always returns nothing. However, when I try the same code in the shell, it works.

```
def getKeywords(the_field='Keyword', the_industry='IT/Computer Science'):
    ret = set()
    for i in Keywords.objects.filter(field=the_field, industry=the_industry):
        ret.add(str(i))
    print(ret)
    return ret
```

Here is the model:

```
    class Keywords(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name
    industry = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 70)
```

Comment: You should never call the double-underscore methods directly; always use the builtin equivalents. `ret.add(str(i))`

Comment: @DanielRoseman I made that method in the models page.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Never call it directly, always use the builtin.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, I changed it but it didn't fix my probelm.

Comment: I didn't say it would, which is why this was not an answer.

Comment: You mean to say ret is being printed from shell but prints nothing from your script or probably your views.? Or are you getting some error while printing from script?

Comment: @ankush no the loop is not even being called at all.

Comment: If the execution is not even entering the for loop, then you can probably use ipdb to debug at which line the execution is getting stuck.
It will be helpful if you could edit your question and provide the complete views/script.

Comment: @ankush I was able to isolate the problem before I posted. Keywords.objects.filter isn't returning anything.

Comment: Okay. I just checked the difference between filter(field=the_field, industry= the_industry) and filter(field=the_field).filter( industry= the_industry).
So can you clarify that whether you want all objects which have field as the_field AND industry as the_industry, or those objects which have either field as the_field OR industry as the_industry.
Because if you want the later, then the way you have written it, won't return any object in case there is one which has field=the_field AND industry=the_industry
See this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi I'm trying to get field=the_field AND industry=the_industry. However, when I was debugging I changed filter(field=the_field, industry= the_industry) to all() and the loop still wasn't called. Plus, When I use the same expression in the shell I get the values I want. For some reason this happens with only this model. In admin, I checked if Keywords had values and they did.

Comment: If after setting the filter to all() also the loop dint execute, then in that case one possibility is that there might something missing with the imports in your script, though technically it should have given some import error.
Its difficult to help you without the complete script.
As I said, using 'ipdb' to debug it is the best solution .

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi The script is correct. When I run the script itself by passing the file to the django shell. I get my set of keywords. So, it can't be the code but when I run my tests using the python manage.py tests command I get no value. All the test does now is call the function.

Comment: Two things I would like to mention here.
Firstly, 'python manage.py test' and not 'tests' is an predefined command for running tests for your code. So are you referring to the same python manage.py test command or have you written your own custom python manage.py tests command?
Secondly, it should be ret = Set() and not ret = set()
because its 'from sets import Set'
See this -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#example

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi tests was a typo I mean python manage.py test and also I am using python 3.5 and it was changed to set instead of Set. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets